# Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/view/ViewStructure

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-support-library

I am building an community directory application for android OS.
It is working fine Lollipop onward devices.Appplication has been sometime
crashed in  Android OS 4.4 version. Error log mentioned below :

```
# Platform: android
# Date: 2017-12-04T08:33:00Z
# OS Version: 4.4.2
# Device: Galaxy S5
# RAM Free: 63.1%
# Disk Free: 69.3%

Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/view/ViewStructure
Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class 
"android.view.ViewStructure" on path: DexPathList[[zip file 
"/data/app/com.blacksmithyouthclub-1.apk", zip file 
"/data/data/com.blacksmithyouthclub/code_cache/secondary-
dexes/com.blacksmithyouthclub-1.apk.classes2.zip"],nativeLibraryDirectories=
[/data/app-lib/com.blacksmithyouthclub-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:656)
at android.view.ViewDebug.getExportedPropertyMethods(ViewDebug.java:960)
at android.view.ViewDebug.exportMethods(ViewDebug.java:1047)
at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewProperties(ViewDebug.java:997)
at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewProperties(ViewDebug.java:983)
at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpView(ViewDebug.java:900)
at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:855)
at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:867)
at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:867)
at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:867)
at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:867)
at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:867)
at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:867)
at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:867)
at android.view.ViewDebug.dump(ViewDebug.java:793)
at android.view.ViewDebug.dispatchCommand(ViewDebug.java:416)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$W.executeCommand(ViewRootImpl.java:6258)
at android.view.IWindow$Stub.onTransact(IWindow.java:65)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(NativeStart.java)
```

Answer (score 0):

> ViewDebug.getExportedPropertyMethods() should only occur if
>   hierarchyviewer / ddm is connected. This is not a user crash.

[Check here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68796830).

Answer (score -3):

[Try it to update support library 27.0.0](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63151548#comment24)

Android Gradle Plugin 3.x:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0' 
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
```

Android Gradle Plugin 2.x:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'

compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.0'
```

Also update compileSdkVersion to 27.

Comment: i don't think it is the solution. I had the same problem and I met your requirements.

Comment: Same problem here. Just happened to me as well. Just after closed alpha release same crash has been reported to crashlytics (just one so far). Same device: Samsung Galaxy S5 with Android 4.4.2. Will see how it goes after wider rollout. support_lib = '27.1.1' buildToolsVersion '27.0.3' target and compile - 27 gradle 4.4, plugin 3.1.1